# DataValidation openpyxl вызывает ошибку

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

Использую библиотеку python openpyxl для создания и записи данных в .xlsx, нужно создать выпадающий список. Создал, проблем нет, но в некоторых выпадающих списках в параметре formula1 содержатся значения с дефисом, например, 'бизнес-план', 'кpacнo-жёлтый'. Когда такие значение приходят для валидации то в файле они не отображаются и выдаёт ошибку. 
Также вопрос, как можно заставить в выпадающем списке эти слова быть с большой буквы? В параметр приходят с болшой, отображаются с маленькой.

Answer (score 0):

Создавать валидатор нужно таким образом

```
formula = 'Some, String, with-some, words'
dv = DataValidation(type='list', formula1='"{}"'.format(formula), allow_blank=True)
```